# How to modify a regular expression to search between a special string and a character?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to search between a special string and a character.

I have a regular expression:

`b(\(.*?)\)`

It looks for matches between "b(" and ")", for example:
String: `az[b('0x611', '0*L3')]`
Match: `b('0x611', '0*L3')`

But sometimes there are lines like this:
String: `(G, f[b('0x4ed', 'S)Oi')])`

And in this case match will be: `b('0x4ed', 'S)`, and that wrong.

I'm trying to solve this by looking for matches between "b('0x4ed', 'S)" and ")", but when I try to bring the regular expression to the following form `b('0x4ed', 'S)(\(.*?)\)`, it stops working.

How could I get out of this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: *"not one or more singlequotes until a singlequote"* like: `'[^']+'`

Example

```
b\('[^']+', ?'[^']+'\)
```

[Demo on Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/fkqzZi/1)

PS: if the *value* can be *empty* `''` use *zero-or-more* `*`:

```
b\('[^']+', ?'[^']*'\)
```